# Get the value from input when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, onclick

Having this code snippet:

```
const MyComponent = ({ e }) => {
  const toggleButton = (e) => {
    console.log('eee: ', e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input className='input-search' type='text' placeholder='search' />
        <Button onClick={(e) => toggleButton(e)}>reset</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I was expecting to see in the log the value from input but it is `undefined`. Any thoughts?

Comment: must be in a form and elemnt must have name or get element by id or name , etc and then get value ; this value poined to butten

Comment: @amir.ashrafi That is not accurate. inputs and buttons can be and often are used outside forms and without ids or names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target` is the button which has no value attribute. You should be [storing the input value in state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) with a `onChange` event. Make sure that the input's value attribute reflects the state, and use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to log the changes to the console.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Example() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`State: ${input}`);
  }, [input])

  function handleClick() {
    setInput('');
  }

  function handleInput(e) {
    const { target: { value } } = e;
    setInput(value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input onChange={handleInput} type="text" placeholder="search" value={input} />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: it logs the text, thanks! however, shouldn't it clear the input if we set the input to "" inside handleClick? Like this `function handleClick(e) { setInput('');}`

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I was just extrapolating my example from your question.

Comment: If you wanted to log that to the console you'd need a `useEffect` hook in there. So I've updated my answer.

Comment: it seems to reset the state but the value remains in the input..

Comment: Use an `onChange` on the input instead, and use the input state in the value. Answer updated.